# Make more efficient Ansible that writes Nagios objects for monitoring Cisco interfaces

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nagios, cisco

I've written a working role that checks Cisco network device non-virtual interfaces, finds and selects trunks that are also up, and writes some Nagios object definitions to monitor status and utilisation.

I've been trying to make it more efficient so that at each stage it only works on interfaces that are interesting:

1. Find all trunks
2. Check only trunks' operational status - not all interfaces' status
3. Write Nagios object definitions only for interfaces that are trunking and up

The code below continues to slowly check every physical interface even if we could have eliminated non-trunks with information already obtained.

What I've been struggling with is shortening the list of interfaces while keeping the correct `iface_index` associated for later reference in the template. I've tried to work with making the `iface_index` a dictionary key with operational status and trunk status other key/value pairs but can't knit it together.

Any inspiration would be greatly appreciated, I feel like there should be a better way. Also apologies in advance for my amateurish code.

```yaml
---

- name: Get physical interface indexes
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  command: "snmpwalk -Oqn -v 3 -l authPriv -u {{ snmpv3user }} -a SHA -A {{ snmpv3_auth_key }} -x AES -X {{ snmpv3_priv_key }} {{ ansible_host }} .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.6.1.1.14"
  register: iface_oids

- name: Extract only the index
  set_fact:
    iface_index: "{{ iface_oids.stdout | regex_findall('\\.([0-9]+) ','last') }}"

- name: Get interface trunk state
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  command: "snmpwalk -Oqv -v 3 -l authPriv -u {{ snmpv3user }} -a SHA -A {{ snmpv3_auth_key }} -x AES -X {{ snmpv3_priv_key }} {{ ansible_host }} .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.6.1.1.14"
  register: iface_trunk_state
  
- name: Get interface oper state
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  command: "snmpwalk -Oqv -v 3 -l authPriv -u {{ snmpv3user }} -a SHA -A {{ snmpv3_auth_key }} -x AES -X {{ snmpv3_priv_key }} {{ ansible_host }} .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ iface_index }}"
  register: iface_oper_state

- name: Get interface descriptions
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  command: "snmpget -Oqv -v 3 -l authPriv -u {{ snmpv3user }} -a SHA -A {{ snmpv3_auth_key }} -x AES -X {{ snmpv3_priv_key }} {{ ansible_host }} .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ iface_index }}"
  register: iface_description

- name: Get interface names
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  loop: "{{ iface_index }}"
  command: "snmpget -Oqv -v 3 -l authPriv -u {{ snmpv3user }} -a SHA -A {{ snmpv3_auth_key }} -x AES -X {{ snmpv3_priv_key }} {{ ansible_host }} .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.{{ item }}"
  register: iface_name

- set_fact:
    nagios_trunks: |
      #
      # Monitor trunking interfaces
      #
      {% for iface in iface_index %}
      {% if (iface_trunk_state.stdout_lines[loop.index0] == "1") and (iface_oper_state.results[loop.index0].stdout[0] == "1") %}
      {% raw %}define service {
      {% endraw %}
          use                     generic-service
          host_name               {{ inventory_hostname }} 
          service_description     {{ inventory_hostname }}:{{ iface_name.results[loop.index0].stdout[1:-1] }} - {{ iface_description.results[loop.index0].stdout[1:-1] }}
          check_command           check-snmp-v3!.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.{{ iface }} -r 1
          notifications_enabled   0
      {% raw %}}
      {% endraw %}
      #
      {% raw %}define service {
      {% endraw %}
          use                     generic-service
          host_name               {{ inventory_hostname }}
          service_description     Link Utilisation INPUT - {{ iface_description.results[loop.index0].stdout[1:-1] }}
          check_command           check-snmp-v3!.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.{{ iface }} --rate
          check_interval          5
          notifications_enabled   0
      {% raw %}}
      {% endraw %}
      #
      {% raw %}define service {
      {% endraw %}
          use                     generic-service
          host_name               {{ inventory_hostname }}
          service_description     Link Utilisation OUTPUT - {{ iface_description.results[loop.index0].stdout[1:-1] }}
          check_command           check-snmp-v3!.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.{{ iface }} --rate
          check_interval          5
          notifications_enabled   0
      {% raw %}}
      {% endraw %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      #
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are doing, is called 'bashism', and it's not a good style. If you are doing something complex with a lot of interconnections between `command`, it's better to use Python and write a good Ansible module. This will make plays simpler, and you have a proper tools at your hand.

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html